# How to use GETELEMENT with an specific position

Tags: javascript, css, position, jsfiddle

I have seen this code ( http://jsfiddle.net/eMNfd/21/ ), but I want to know how to make the new div can be created to the right of the blue, that is, in horizontal mode.

```js
document.getElementById("text").onclick = function () {
    var ok = true;

     if (ok === true) {
          var div = document.createElement('div');
           
          div.className = 'new-rect';       
            //div.style.backgroundColor = "black";

       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    }
};
```

```css
.new-rect {
    background: black;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" style="width:20%;height:30px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Thanks to all.

Comment: How about  float them to the left ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float` for this (has to be set on all `div`s to work), you can also use `inline-block`:

```js
document.getElementById("text").onclick = function () {
    var ok = true;

     if (ok === true) {
          var div = document.createElement('div');
           
          div.className = 'new-rect';       
            //div.style.backgroundColor = "black";

       document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
    }
};
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 0; /* to get rid of the space between the divs */
  white-space: nowrap; /* to prevent wrapping on multiple lines */
}

div {
  display: inline-block; /* to add divs horizontally */
}

.new-rect {
    background: black;
    width: 20%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text" style="width:20%;height:30px;background-color:blue;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but using float, when the width of the page is completed, the div will continue to create a bottom line to blue div. I'm looking for that div are always created on the left.